# how can i union 2 columns to one row

Tags: sql

i have this table

```
DEVICE_NAME     AMOUNT_LEVEL1   DEVICE_NAME AMOUNT_LEVEL2 
2477885               3              
2479936               4          2479922        4
2478974              62          2478712        62
2478358               8          2478348        8
2477703               3     
2477911               6          2477713        6
2477835               1
```

and i need the data order like

```
DEVICE_NAME AMOUNT_LEVEL1   AMOUNT_LEVEL2 
2477885           3 
2479936           4 
2478974          62 
2478358           8 
2477703           3 
2477911           6 
2477835           1 
2479922                           4
2478712                           62
2478348                           8
2477713                           6
```

i have tried to use union but did not succeed to get the required result
what query will do the trick ?
Thank you

Comment: Add your query that did not work

Comment: Hint: select `NULL`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT
 device_name_1,
 amount_level_1,
 NULL as amount_level_2
FROM 
 some_table
WHERE device_name_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
 device_name_2,
 NULL as amount_level_1,
 amount_level_2
FROM 
 some_table
WHERE device_name_2 IS NOT NULL
```